# cakePHP, what to do next?

Tags: security, cakephp, deployment

I've followed some tutorials about cakePHP and now it's done, the "mvc" is ready.

What should I do next?
Meaning: I was working locally, can I simply upload the complete app online and it is secured as 'they' meant it to be?
I've downloaded the 1.3.6 package from https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/archives/1.3, and deployed it as is in a folder named as my domain.

Edit:
I have win-xp with wamp.
I created the app by simply unzipping the file to a folder and then renamed it to 'domain_name'.
Then I made the db connection and set the configuration files.
At that point I created the models, views and controllers.
Now the application is working, locally.
My question is: can I simply upload everything to my server, to the html root folder and say that "I am done"?

Comment: Can you clarify your question about being secured?

Comment: I hope that my answer answers your question.  "Done" depends on what your goals are.  Are you looking for it to be working or more than that?  Testing is one way to tell if you've reached your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways that you can deploy your cake app (Development, Production and Advanced), and all of them are secure:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/912/Installation

I would recommended the Production install if you aren't going to run any other apps on this server.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your app isn't already in production, putting it online can tell you more about how it's working.  For instance, you'll learn if there are missing modules or dependencies that must be installed on the live server.

If it's an already live system, you may want to use an online staging server to understand what needs to be modified on the production server in order to have a smooth deployment.

Comment: Seems like I missed the production 'thing'. yes, my meaning is going production with the application. I already tested it

Comment: So do you already have visitors at yourdomain.com?  If you deploy this and it breaks are there any users relying on it working?  If so, proceed with caution.  If no one knows it exists yet except for you and people at your company, then your production server really isn't a production server until you get users.  In that case, deploy away! :)

Comment: 1) I have about 30, uniques, a day.  
2) My worries are not about 'unbreakable' app, it is breakable as any other app :)  
I simply want to know if the cakePHP package, as downloaded from the website, is a 'ready to use' one, or should I make changes in the production env'.. and, thanks for the time and effort.

Comment: The CakePHP core is stable (up to v1.3.x at the moment) and as such is "production-ready". An installation using the documented [development install](http://book.cakephp.org/view/913/Development) is just as secure as any standard Joomla/Wordpress/etc install on shared hosting in the wild (all PHP files in document root). The documented [production install](http://book.cakephp.org/view/914/Production) is for bigger websites who don't share hosting and have access to change Apache settings (can store PHP files outside document root).